# Objective-C style retrieving from .plist not working in Swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, plist

I was was retrieving data in a .plist in Objective-C whenever my view loaded by the following method -

```
@interface ListTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation ListTableViewController
NSArray *dict;

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSString *arr= [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];

    arr=[arr stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"datalist.plist"];
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager]fileExistsAtPath:arr])
    {
       dict=[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:arr];
        NSLog(@"%@",dict);

    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

Now for Swift I am doing the same thing as -

```
class ListTableViewController: UITableViewController{
  var arr = NSArray()
  var plistfinalpath = String()

  override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool){
      let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0]
      plistfinalpath = path.stringByAppendingString("/login.plist")
      print(plistfinalpath)
      print("time of appearing\(arr)")

      arr = NSArray(contentsOfFile: plistfinalpath)!
      self.tableView.reloadData()
  }
}
```

But since I have to unwrap the value in the line `arr = NSArray(contentsOfFile: plistfinalpath)!` when the plist is empty when the app is launched for the first time the array is empty and since I am unwrapping it, it shows an error. So how can I achieve what I was doing in objective C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define your `arr` variable as optional, like this :
`var arr:NSArray? = NSArray()`

When a variable is defined as non optional, you cannot make it `nil`. The `NSArray` initializer you used is defined as `public convenience init?(contentsOfFile path: String)` - the `?` means, that it can in fact return a `nil`. When you used `!`, you force unwrapped the value, which results in runtime crash when the value is `nil`.

As always, you can read more in the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html)

---

Alternatively, you can do something like this :

```
if let tempArr = NSArray(contentsOfFile: plistfinalpath) {
    arr = tempArr
}
```

This way, you don't need to have your `arr` defined as optional and will only assign to it, when the contents of file where not empty.

Comment: Can you give the reason why I was getting an error like this?

Comment: I've expaned my answer a little

Comment: I did that and I had to give an exclamation mark in all places in my code expect in this block.

Comment: That's becaus now your `arr` is optional. I've provided an alternative way, which may in fact be better for you.

Comment: But when at the first time of launching of application it would also try to load the table view content and since I am unwrapping it in my other datasource method, it may lead to fatal error.

Comment: Not necessarily - if you return to a non-optional `arr`, as in your original code, and use the `if let`, you will have an empty array if the file was empty(because of how you initialise it), and non empty if there were some contents in the file.

Comment: But doing so my table view is empty whenever I load it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97276/discussion-between-losiowaty-and-g-abhisek).

Answer (score 4):

A complete answer involves understanding the concept of "optional".

## What is an optional?

In Swift you can declare a variable as optional appending a `?` after the type. When you do so, it means that the variable can hold a value or not at all. While when you declare a variable as non-optional, the compiler ensures that it holds a value at all times.

- Declaring a variable as optional: `var myOptionalVariable: NSArray?`
- Declaring a variable as not optional: `var myVariable = NSArray()`

Note how in the non optional var, we're forced by the compiler to give it a value (that in this case is just an empty array). This because the compiler grants that when a variable is not optional, it holds a value in every moment. **Notice the difference**: the first statement just *declares* the variable as an optional *NSArray*, the second statement *initializes and assigns* a new empty *NSArray* to the variable.

## Why optional is useful?

With the introduction of optionals we have compile time safety about existence of the data contained on our variables. When not using an optional variable, we know for sure that a variable holds a value all the time. At the same time, when using an optional variable, we're forced to deal with the case where a value might be not there, instead of dealing with it silently (that is what happens with `nil` in objective-c). Extracting value from an optional is called **unwrapping**

## Unwrapping Optionals (i.e. extract value from optional)

To "extract" the value from an optional variable, you need to unwrap it. There are several ways to unwrap an optional, given `myOptional` is an optional variable, here some examples:

```
if let variable = myOptional { 
    // I can safely use variable here
}
```

or even this other syntax:

```
variable = myOptional ?? defaultNonOptionalValue
// I can safely use variable here
```

Also, you can do a forced unwrap with

```
variable = myOptional!
// crash incoming?
```

You used this way to do the unwrap, but really you're saying to the compiler "*Trust me, I know that `myOptional` will never be nil*" that in your case is not true, and it leads to a crash with the error `Fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional values`. You should always avoid forced unwrapped, unless you're really really sure about your data.

## Long Story Short

You have 2 viable solutions:

- Do not use forced unwrap (see options above about unwrapping)
- Convert your variable `arr` to an optional (by declaring it in this way: `var arr: NSArray?`) and then deal with a (non-forced) unwrap when you use it (i.e. in your tableView datasource methods)

Which one is more correct for your case, depends on the `arr` meaning, if it makes sense to be optional, then go for it, otherwise, just leave it non optional and assign some default value.

Comment: Okay if I declare my above array as var arr:NSArray? = NSArray() . Then I don't need to check whether its nill or not but when I implement it in my program,I have to unwrap it at every point in my program.  So lets say in my  first VC is table view controller and I am using an optional array. For the first time when app launches it would be empty and since we have unwrapped it in all points in our code like return arr!.count ,  it would obviously result in error.

Comment: couldn't get you. Can you join me on the chat

Comment: I don't know if we can meet on our schedule, try to re-read my answer and let me know what it's not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the following code,

```
if let array = NSArray(contentsOfFile: plistfinalpath){
   arr = array
}
```

In swift, (!) is used to forced unwrapping an optional values.
You should use that when the optionals have a value, otherwise you should use the above code.