# Is NSMutableArray instance, optional by default in SWIFT?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, nsmutablearray, option-type

I have been using this following thing to do my plist and save data and display contents of plist in a Table View. I am using a NSMutableArray to fetch the contents of the array and display it in the table view . VC1 is my table view & VC2 is my EnterDetail VC So I have declared my code as follows -

```
class ListTableViewController: UITableViewController
{
var arr = NSMutableArray()

    var plistfinalpath = String()

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()


    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }
    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool)
    {


            let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0]
            plistfinalpath = path.stringByAppendingString("/login.plist")
            print(plistfinalpath)
        arr = (NSMutableArray(contentsOfFile: plistfinalpath))!
            print("time of appearing\(arr)")

       /* if let temparray = NSMutableArray(contentsOfFile: plistfinalpath)
        {
            arr = temparray
        }*/




        self.tableView.reloadData()

    }
```

So as you can see that I have declared a 'arr' as a NSMutableArray type and it is not optional. And when I use in my didappear() the compiler forces me to force unwrap it. Why is that so why does it happens evenif I have declared 'arr' as non optional? And here comes the real problem whenever I run my app for the first time the plist is empty implies 'arr' is also empty. And since I have used forced unwrapping my app crashes due to fatal error. And if I uncomment my commented line in the above code, the if let part, it works fine . So any suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no trouble with your NSMutableArray.

```
var arr = NSMutableArray()
```

create non optional instance of an array. so far, so good ... An expression

```
NSMutableArray(contentsOfFile: plistfinalpath)
```

can return nil, so it returns the optional value. Here you try to create another instance of NSMutableArray and assign the result to your var arr.

> A mutable array containing the contents of the file specified aPath.
>   Returns nil if the file can’t be opened or if the contents of the file
>   can’t be parsed into a mutable array.

Probably the best way for you is something like

```
import Foundation
var arr = NSMutableArray(contentsOfFile: "somePath") ?? NSMutableArray()
```

Here your variable is guaranty to have the default value (an empty instance of NSMutableArray) if the file does not exist yet (or other failure happened)

Comment: So how to solve the issue . Is it only to check by if let also if it is non optional.

Comment: yes, if let ... or guard let ... will help you. you check an Optional value, not an arr variable!! you create there new instance, it has nothing with your arr var. if temparray is not nil, if let unwrap its value and next you assign this new value to var arr (you replace the old one)

Comment: Oh so the whole concept lies in the fact that whenever I am declaring a variable as var arr = NSMutableArray(), it is non optional, but when I am giving it the contents of my file , SWIFT immediately knows that it is a non optional var having optional value. That's the reason why it is asking me to unwrap it at the first point. isn't it ?

Comment: no!!!! your var arr is not optional! the result of expression NSMutableArray(contentsOfFile: plistfinalpath) is.

Comment: you are not able to assign optional value to nonoptional variable. so you have to try to bind ( if let temparray = .... ) an unoptional result to temparray, or if it is not available, do something else.

Comment: So if i create an optional variable of NSMutableArray, do i need to check by if let

Answer (score 0):

To resolve your fatal error check your file exist or not :-

```
   //Check whether your file exist or not
 let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0]
        plistfinalpath = path.stringByAppendingString("/login.plist")
    if NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(plistfinalpath)
    {
        arr = (NSMutableArray(contentsOfFile: plistfinalpath))!
    }
```

Comment: there is still no guaranty that a NSMutableArray can be created from the file.

Answer (score -1):

Declare it like

```
var arr : NSMutableArray = []

// Or

var arr : NSMutableArray!
```

Comment: So what is the problem in this var arr = NSMutableArray() ?

Comment: when you make it with ( ) , this means with options. when it is with [ ] means with no options.

Comment: Okay fine can you just check out with the answer in  -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34154199/objective-c-style-retrieving-from-plist-not-working-in-swift/34154251?noredirect=1#comment56057061_34154251.

Comment: In that answer a guy has said - Declaring a variable as optional: var myOptionalVariable: NSArray?
Declaring a variable as not optional: var myVariable = NSArray()